# Sitecore: Why is my piped query only returning one set of results for my droptree?

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

In Sitecore I am trying to set the `source` field to a query that will pull multiple folders for selecting an item from a `droptree`.

Example:

```
query:/sitecore/content/Sites/Global/Data/TabPanels|./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site']/Data/TabPanels
```

I expect this query to return:

1. The children of `sitecore/content/Sites/Global/Data/TabPanels`
2. The children of the current site's `Data/TabPanels` folder

However, when I run the query, I only get the children of `/sitecore/content/Sites/Global/Data/TabPanels`. Likewise, when I reverse the order of the piped queries, and list `./ancestor-or-self...` first, only the children of the current site's `Data/TabPanels` folder show up in the `droptree`.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately **Droptree** control in **Sitecore** doesn't support multiple roots so you can not use query for 2 folders to set them as the roots of the tree.

If you want to select one of the children of the `sitecore/content/Sites/Global/Data/TabPanels` or one of the children of the current site's `Data/TabPanels` folder, you can use **Droplink** field type instead of **Droptree** and add `/*` to both of the query parts:

```
query:/sitecore/content/Sites/Global/Data/TabPanels/*|./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site']/Data/TabPanels/*
```